# OpenGL ES 2.0 texture on a single trianlge in a mesh

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to draw texture on a quad which has two triangles. But my objective is to draw texture on a single triangle only (within a mesh), the other triangle is to be left empty.

How can i achieve this ? any sample program or pseudo code will be of a lot help.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below

1. Check if vertices are correct using the frag shader.
   gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0); // The rectangle must be red
2. If 1. is okay, check uv values.

   if 1. is not okay. use this vertices and uv values.

   vertices = -1.0,-1.0, 1.0,-1.0, -1.0,1.0, 1.0,1.0
   UVs =  0.0,0.0, 1.0,0.0, 0.0,1.0, 1.0,1.0

That's it. You are all set for the next step

Comment: but these steps will draw the texture on the quad (two triangles). i want to draw the texture on a single triangle only.

Comment: take that off using a frag shader like if(fragCoord.x>fragCoord.y)
    fragColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    else fragColor = texture;

Comment: Well, thanks. This is what i wanted. But now one more hiccup i am facing is , the texture in the second triangle should fit but rather it looks to be scaled. Should i play around with the texture co-ordinates ???

Comment: Did you use any matrix there? I don't get why the texture is scaled. If the rectangle and the texture have same ratio there is nothing to change in the vertices. Yes, you should change UVs anyway to make that fit. Refer to a tutorial http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial16/tutorial16.html

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial, it is of great help. But in the same tutorial code samples, if i replace the texture file with a image, the image gets wrapped on two faces of triangle, rather than each face getting its own image.

Comment: Could you show how it looks? I don't understand what the difference between its own image  and the texture file are. Why do you use two files if you want to see only one?